# Get latitude/longitude from BigQuery Geography Point

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a field with type GEOGRAPHY in BigQuery, but I now want to display each point on a map in DataStudio.

It seems an efficient way to do this is to use the coordinates, but I do not know how to extract lat and lng separately from the GEOGRAPHY data type.

The following all don't work:

```
SELECT locationCoords.lat FROM dataTable
```

```
SELECT locationCoords.latitude FROM dataTable
```

```
SELECT locationCoords[0] FROM dataTable
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the Geography functions `ST_X` and `ST_Y`.

```sql
SELECT 
  ST_X(locationCoords) as longitude,
  ST_Y(locationCoords) as latitude 
FROM 
  dataTable
```

[Geography Functions DOC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: No worries ! :) If the answer fits your needs, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: You are amazing! I was looking exactly for something like this.